# How to view memory allocation stacktrace in Java VisualVM

Tags: java, memory-leaks, visualvm

This article describes how to view memory allocation stacktrace in Java VisualVM: http://rejeev.blogspot.de/2009/04/analyzing-memory-leak-in-java.html

In short, define a custom preset in the Java VisualVM options and check the **"record allocations stack traces" checkbox** in the memory settings tab.

Now, when I select that custom preset and start memory profiling, I still cannot view the memory allocation stacktrace. There is no right-click-on-item action **"Take snapshot and show allocation stack traces"** as described in the article, nor a anything like that. I am using VisualVM 1.7.

How can I view these allocation stack traces?

Comment: Where are you looking for that right click action 'Take snapshot and show allocation stack traces'? Did you select particular class in the live results table?

Comment: Check that your JDK and JVM are compatible (for example, they are both 32-bit or both 64-bit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable **Memory** profiling in **Sampler** tab, then press a **Heap Dump** button.

Comment: This is something different - heap dump does not show you allocation stack traces. In addition - to get the heap dump, you don't need to use 'Memory' profiling in'Sampler' tab. You can take a heap dump from 'Monitor' tab or from the context menu of the monitored application.

Comment: Agreed this is an answer to a different question, although it's a useful approach. Eclipse Memory Analyzer is really helpful for analyzing heap dumps, but the VisualVM snapshot with allocation traces is really helpful independently.

Comment: Excuse the downvote: it was *accidental* (i must have clicked on it while trying to go to a different page)!  There is a knee-jerk rule for SOF that after 5 mins your vote is locked in. Sorry about that!

Comment: Besides that you can also take a look at the thread allocations then click on Deltas to see which thread is allocating more bytes (its more useful for multithreaded)

Answer (score 22):

If you can't see this option, go to Profiler -> activate "Settings" check box and activate "Record allocation stack traces" while the profiler is not active.

Comment: Also, while the profiler is running, you need to click the snapshot button, only then you can right click and view the allocation stack traces.